# How to use DeviceActivityExtension or Shield in swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Someone can tell me how to use DeviceActivityExtension or Shield or where to learn about it

I used it but got some errors that's I've to ask !

someone can suggest the playlist or course for learning swift for iOS development !